# Android recyclerView is not scrolling smoothly with a lot of views to bind on older device

Tags: android, performance, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I  have a `recyclerView` with an `adapter` that is inflating a custom layout (`Folding cell` library). after inflating, in `onCreateViewHolder`, I am initializing a lot of views (mostly `textViews`) like below:

```
@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

FoldingCell v = (FoldingCell) LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
        .inflate(R.layout.custom_layout, parent, false);


    ConstraintLayout continueBTN = v.findViewById(R.id.continueBTN);
    TextView num = v.findViewById(R.id.num);
    TextView name = v.findViewById(R.id.name);
    TextView surname = v.findViewById(R.id.surname);
    TextView add = v.findViewById(R.id.add);
    TextView add2 = v.findViewById(R.id.add2);
    TextView currency = v.findViewById(R.id.currency);
    TextView currency2 = v.findViewById(R.id.currency2);
    ConstraintLayout del = v.findViewById(R.id.DeleteICN);
    ConstraintLayout rnme = v.findViewById(R.id.renameBtn);
    TextView fText = v.findViewById(R.id.fText);
    TextView tText = v.findViewById(R.id.tText);
    TextView continue = v.findViewById(R.id.cnt);
    TextView total= v.findViewById(R.id.total);
    FoldingCell cell = v.findViewById(R.id.fcell);


    ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(cell, continueBTN,num, name, surname, add, add2, price, currency, currency2, del, rnme, fText, tText, continue,total );

    vh.bind(onCardClickListener);

    return vh;
}
```

The above views are all subject to change via BaaS which Is why I am inserting them in a `viewHolder` if that makes sense. `cell`  view is the container which is holding the other views above, which I also need to initialize since if a recycled `Folding cell` happens to be unfolded then when scrolled on-screen again I want to leave it unfolded, since by default, a `folding cell` is folded.

Therefore in `onBindViewHolder` this is what I am doing:

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    // if this view holder position was left unfolded
        if (unfoldedIndexes.contains(position)) {

            // show it as unfolded again
            holder.cell.unfold(true);

            // only bind the views created in onCreateViewHolder that correspond to the unfolded state of the cell
            bindUnfoldedState(holder, holder.getLayoutPosition());
        }else{
            holder.cell.fold(true);

        // only bind the  views created in onCreateViewHolder that correspond to the folded state of the cell 
            bindFoldedState(holder, holder.getLayoutPosition());
        }
    }

public void bindFoldedState(ViewHolder holder, int position){

    CustomLayout customLayout = myArrayList.get(position);
    String formattedPrice = context.getString(R.string.currency, customLayout.getP());

    holder.currency.setText(formattedPrice);

    holder.add.setText(customLayout.getConName());

    holder.num.setText(customLayout.getNum());

    holder.total.setText(""+customLayout.getTotal());

}

public void bindUnfoldedState(ViewHolder holder, int position){

           holder.tText.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#6F90CF"));
            holder.fText.setText(location.getToTime());
     //  …
     // and the rest of the views exactly the same way

        if (location.getRequestBtnClickListener() != null) {

            // seting some onClickListeners on views
        }
}
```

This all works well and good. .. on emulator. However, on a real device (old, used, 2015 api 23 Galaxy A5) the app is dropping a lot of frames when a new view enters the screen, making scrolling jerky. dev tools on device show that it is taking more than 16ms to bind data.

**To confirm this, i commented all the code in`onBindViewHolder()` and the scrolling is as smooth as it should be.**

So the question is, how can I bind all the above data in a fast way? each element in the `recyclerView` has all the above child views that might change through BaaS.

I also do not have the flattest hierarchy in the layout I created. I am using Constraint Layout exclusively which might help but I do not believe that the problem is originating from the hierarchy since by `onBindViewHolder()` test I mentioned above.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Update you `onCreateViewHolder` method as:

```
@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
 FoldingCell v=LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.custom_layout, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(v);
}
```

Create a view holder like this:

```
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {  
        public ConstraintLayout continueBTN 
        public TextView textView,name,surname,add;  

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {  
            super(itemView);  
            continueBTN = (ConstraintLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.continueBTN);  
            num= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.num);
            name= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            surname= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.surname);
            add= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.add);
           /...../          
             }  
    }
```

And if your recycler view is inside nested scrollview use this line:

```
  recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

Use your bindViewHolder as it is.
Hope this should help you

Comment: Basically you are finding your Views in the '_OncreateViewholder_' method. so you have to find your views on "ViewHolder".

Comment: this might have helped a bit but the scrolling is still very jerky when `onBindViewHolder()` is invoked

Comment: Try `adapter.setHasStableIds(true);` it maintain your items with unique ids:  and make sure your `onBindViewHolder()` is as light as possible.